# Firebase: How to read from external DB?

Tags: postgresql, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have some data in PostgreSQL on another server that I need to read to include in my Firebase app, and then render charts. I only have the db connection string, there are no endpoints there to return that data.

- I would restrict entering connection string to admin, using auth and roles on Firebase.
- Then I need a way for Firebase app to grab that data with SQL and show on client, which would render tables and charts.
- The user should never be able to see the connection strings, even in network traffic.

Is this doable and how?

Comment: The question here is why do you want to do that? You've already got data in an SQL Database and can generate the tables and charts. a) why do you want to move that data to Firebase... i.e. what's the advantage / use case.  b) do you have a plan for refactoring your SQL tables into JSON objects? Is there a consideration for Joins or other SQL functions (searches etc).

Comment: @Jay I'd like to build a client facing app on Firebase where they can register and each customer does certain things, among other, watches his data from Postgres in tables and charts. So I would use Firebase's NoSQL for everything except that piece of data that's already on PG.

Comment: Okay - so you don't need to actually migrate any SQL data from SQL to Firebase. You would just need to review the resulting data in a chart if I am understanding correctly. Things get a bit vacuous from there as we don't know what a 'db connection string' is and additionally don't know what/where/how the resultant data set is stored. Can it be downloaded as a flat file or is it stored in another SQL table. I think you'll need to enhance your question with more data to really understand the scope.

Comment: DB connection string is in the standard format username:password@host:port/dbname. Data is stored as any other data, in tables, it can be retrieved by SQL or some adapter, ORM and whatnot.

Comment: Since Firebase doesn't have server side code, you won't be able to directly have Firebase get the SQL data - it will have to go through the client. You could encrypt the network string, but that doesn't the help as the client would still have to connect to the SQL server. What about storing the data in Firebase and not using the SQL server?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem to solve and as a **temporary solution** I initialized app  with firebase admin serviceAccount. Then listened for changes of firebase collection on my server and on new value received inserted\updated the values in PostgreSQL.

Initialize app as admin and listen for changes on firebase:

```
  admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: 'https://yourfirebaseproject.firebaseio.com',
  });

  const db = admin.database();

  db.ref('User').on('value', async (snapshot) => {
    insertOrUpdate(User, 'users', snapshot.val());
  });
```

Insert\update data into PostgreSQL:

```
const insertOrUpdate = (model, tableName, data) => {
  const firstData = data[0] ? data[0] : data;

  return model.knex().raw(
    knex(tableName).insert(data).toQuery() + ' ON CONFLICT ("id") DO UPDATE SET ' +
      Object.keys(firstData).map((field) => `${field}=EXCLUDED.${field}`).join(', ')
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase has no "sync with PostgreSQL" API.

So either you app will need to do that (meaning that it has access to both the PostgreSQL an the Firebase Database) or you'll need to set up a server to do so.

Since you already ruled that the app can't know the PostgreSQL connection string, that only leaves doing this on a server (or some other place that the general users don't have access to).

Beyond that the scenario is incredibly broad. There are many, many ways to implement it.

Comment: The problem is that Firebase doesn't have the option of having server code. It would be easy in that case. Now it seems impossible.

Comment: We know that allowing you to run your code on Firebase's servers would allow more people to implement their use-cases without needing a server. I also know from experience that most developers overestimate what it means to run code-that-requires-elevated-permission (such as yours). It can be a tiny VM/container, a box you have at home, I often joke that it can even be your own Android phone. The difference between a client and a serve app in this case is that one of them is *your* Android phone, the other one is *my* Android phone". It's about trust, not about computing power.